# Combine [api-manager] to [wso2-am], possibly rename to [wso2am]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are two tags for WSO2 Api Manager: [api-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-manager) and [wso2-am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2-am). The latter is more in conformity to [wso2esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2esb), [wso2cep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2cep) etc, but still a bit different.

Suggestion: retag [api-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-manager) to [wso2-am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2-am), rename [wso2-am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2-am) to [wso2am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2am) for consistency. [api-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-manager) shouldn't be needed even as a synonym.

Comment: There are 17 questions which are tagged [api-manager] and not [wso2]. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api-manager+-wso2 . These might be related to some other technology. Given that it's an ambiguous tag, I certainly would agree with the synonymization. If you can review those 17 questions, then we can combine the tags.

Answer (score 1):

doesn't api-manager refer to different api-manager products ?
We first need to make sure that all questions tagged with api-manager are asked about wso2 API manager. If so we can do the retagging.

Comment: Relevant to anyone active in the WSO2 tags: [Proposed updates to WSO2 tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418604/1478931)